# Fullcalendar external events, resource limitation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Ok so here is the deal. I am using FullCalendar, premium version V3. I am currently developing Drag/Drop external events, which have no associated hours. Currently I have 4 (depending on the settings in DB) resources. The problem is, that when I try to drag an external event to any other resource, different from 1, the event continues to stay in resource 1.

If anyone has came across this problem, please give a hint on how to fix this issue. I think it is because I am using a custom view for the Agenda, but I am not sure, because the view has not been developed by me.

Thank you in advance! :)

Screenshot of what is happening:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24sgc.png)

Comment: You'll need to show us (the relevant parts of) your code, especially if some of it is custom...I can't think of any reason in theory why you can't drop events into the correct resource

Comment: Here is a fiddle, but if I have to upload all the code with the custom agenda, I will need to archive it. https://jsfiddle.net/b0pogcj2/

Comment: Thanks but I was actually hoping for an example which reproduces the error...i.e. one which I can run. I can't run that code because it seems to include some templating code which isn't executed, and I can't see a calendar or anything I could drag onto it. Try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - we don't need all your code, just the parts which actually impact on this problem.